# Looking to have a <hr> and <h3> together

Tags: html, css

[image]

Like the example above. I've found some helpful script with the a small img which I do like however I don't know how to get the padding about the title so the line doesn't go straight through.

```
h3.line {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(../images/line.jpg);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Which shows this.
[image]

Any suggestion or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `<span>` for example in your `<h3>` and make it have the same background as your  `<h3>` but without the line so the `<span>` effectively overlaps the `<h3>`.

You can say this to your span:

```
span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

to make it center. You can add width and height to it too. `line-height` helps place your text to the middle vertically.

If you want to spare images than you can use `text-decoration: line-through;` to draw a line through your text.

Comment: This also works. I love have many different ways there are to so something. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can have a 1px dot image which you can place as a background on the `H3`. Then have a span element in between which have a background on.

CSS:

```
h3 {
    background: url(images/dot.png) left center repeat-x;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 span { background: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px; }
```

HTML:

```
<h3><span>About</span></h3>
```

Comment: I've been testing it out and I will be placing multiple ones on different background colours. Am I just going to add a new class and call upon it for each colour or is there an easier way?

Comment: Instead of multiple classes you can just do an inline style if you want a quicker way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the CSS border property instead of an image.

the html:

```
<h2>
  <span>This is a test</span>
  <div></div>
</h2>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
h2 {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    line-height:26px;
    position:relative;
}

span {
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
h2 > div {
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    top:-13px; /* half the line-height of the containing element */
}
```

[A fiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/cgLove/p939u/1/)

The `<div>` is placed inside the heading element, and positioned half-way up by settings its top position to one-half the height of the heading element, which is the headings line-height. z-index is used on the span and div so that the span gets a higher stack order than the div and obscures the (border) line where there is overlap.

Comment: Hey, I like the idea behind not having to use an image however I have many titles throughout my layout that would require this and wouldn't it just up the amount of <div>'s I don't need?

Comment: sure would, though i'm not sure it would cause any problems - is there something particular your worried about?

Comment: Nothing in particular, just seen in forums and read about divitis or something like that and I guess I try to avoid divs when I don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon another way of achieving this.

```
h1
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 26%;
}

h1:before,
h1:after
{
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 );
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Taken from: http://osvaldas.info/blog/background-independent-css-bars